# Converting nested for loops to foreach in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, parallel-processing, dataframe

I have written a function with 2 for loops nested within a foreach loop. I have a list of dataframes that I am trying to loop through in the structure of: `[[5]][10,30]`.

However, I am trying to run this function with 1,000,000 paths (i.e. `for (i in 1:1000000)`), and obviously, the performance is terrible.

I'd really like to run this in parallel with `foreach` loops. I have found that using any form of `apply` functions in conjunction with foreach does not work properly as well. Of course, if there are even better ways to do this, I'd love to see those too:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

# input: matr is a list of 5 matrices
cum_returns <- function(matr) {
  time_horizon <- 30
  paths <- 10
  asset <- 5

  foreach (x = matr) %dopar% {
    for (i in 1:paths) {
      x[i,] <- append(x[i,],100,0)
      for (m in 2:(time_horizon + 1)) {
        # loop through each row of matrix to apply function
        x[i,m] <- x[i,m-1] + x[i,m]
      }
    }
    return(x)
  }
}
```

The goal of the function is to convert dataframes in this format:

```
                   V1          V2         V3            V4         V5         V6
result.4   -0.3937681  0.42309970 -0.2283395 -0.8331735437  0.7874238 -0.1453797
result.9   -1.5680301  0.41994580 -2.1580822  1.6118210199 -1.1626008  1.7275690
result.4.1 -0.5495332 -0.82372187  0.3571042  1.0774779108 -0.7305624  0.6109353
result.9.1 -0.6323561  1.70637893  0.6652303  0.7848319013 -1.0563251  0.8036310
result.4.2 -0.3242765 -0.75415454  0.7407225 -1.7877216475  1.5852460  0.1917951
result.9.2 -0.5348290 -0.05270434  1.5113037  0.8491153876 -2.0715359 -2.0216315
result.4.3 -0.7013342 -0.89451784 -0.2683157 -0.2759993796  0.2709717  1.3437261
result.9.3  1.6187813 -1.53112097  0.6938031 -1.4157996794 -0.6058584  0.4324761
result.4.4 -0.6069532  0.07735158  0.7632158  1.0759685528 -0.3157746 -1.1726851
result.9.4 -0.4945204  1.20070722 -0.1619356 -0.0009728659 -2.0367133  1.4713883
```

To this format, through appending 100 at the start of each row then adding each of the following values in each row to create a cumulative sum in each row's fields:

```
            V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6
result.4   100  99.60623 100.02933  99.80099  98.96782  99.75524
result.9   100  98.43197  98.85192  96.69383  98.30565  97.14305
result.4.1 100  99.45047  98.62674  98.98385 100.06133  99.33076
result.9.1 100  99.36764 101.07402 101.73925 102.52408 101.46776
result.4.2 100  99.67572  98.92157  99.66229  97.87457  99.45982
result.9.2 100  99.46517  99.41247 100.92377 101.77289  99.70135
result.4.3 100  99.29867  98.40415  98.13583  97.85983  98.13080
result.9.3 100 101.61878 100.08766 100.78146  99.36566  98.75981
result.4.4 100  99.39305  99.47040 100.23361 101.30958 100.99381
result.9.4 100  99.50548 100.70619 100.54425 100.54328  98.50657
```

Comment: I don't think you need both for loops. Just the inner one.

Comment: but i need to loop through both columns and rows in the dataframe? is there a way to do that with just one loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to loop over the rows and columns. You can use R's ability to do vectorized calculations to add whole columns together, and replace the repeated calls to append() with a single call to cbind().

```
foreach (x = matr) %dopar% {
  x <- cbind(100,x)
  for (m in 2:(time_horizon + 1)) {
    # loop through each row of matrix to apply function
    x[,m] <- x[,m-1] + x[,m]
  }
  x  
}
```

Even without using multiple cores on my computer this is pretty quick with 1,000,000 rows in each matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Building on atiretoo's answer, you can vectorize this even more resulting in easy parallelization.  Also, there is a built in function to do what you are trying to do on each row, `cumsum` (although for some reason my output is transposed and has to be fixed).

```
library(parallel)
mclapply(matr, 
    function (x) {
       x <- cbind(100,x)
       return(t(apply(x,1,cumsum))
    }
```

You could parallelize further by replacing the `apply` with `parRapply`.  Note that these functions only work on Linux systems, and you'll need to use different methods from the `parallel` package on Windows.

Comment: I thought about apply and cumsum, but decided to accept at face value the use of foreach and that apply didn't work inside it. I had to use doSNOW on my windows box.