# R simplify nested for loop which removes rows from a global variable

Tags: r, foreach

The program should *remove* rows from `pts`. I would like to use nested operator `%:%` instead of nested `for` loops if possible, but I'm not sure how to use rbind/append in a *removing* way (eg. if `x=0.1,y=0.15` removes 3 rows and `x=0.5,y=-0.25` removes 3 different rows then the output at the end will have at least 6 less rows).

```r
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
require(data.table)

shiftReduceRaster = function (x, y) {
  r <- raster::shift(r, x*xres(r), y*yres(r))
  # get cell numbers
  cells <- cellFromXY(r, pts)
  # pick one point per cell
  sel <- aggregate(pts, list(cells), function(i)i[1])
  assign("pts", sel[,c("X", "Y",'id')], envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

sort_abs <- function(x, na.last = TRUE, decreasing = FALSE) {
    x[order(abs(x), na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)] 
}

shiftIntervals = sort_abs(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.05)) # start with 0,0

df1 = fread(file = '~/test.csv',na.strings = '')

pts <- df1[,c("X", "Y",'id')]

r = raster(ncol=36000, nrow=18000, vals=1) # takes 8GB of RAM

for (x in shiftIntervals) {
  for (y in shiftIntervals) {
    shiftReduceRaster(x, y)
  }
  gc()
}

rm(r)
gc()
fwrite(pts, file = '~/output.csv')
```

Can I use rapply or this? [Converting nested for loops to foreach in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634405/converting-nested-for-loops-to-foreach-in-r)

it could process in parallel and then output `pts` only the ids which exist in all 41^2 outputs

some example data:
https://gist.github.com/chapmanjacobd/7d51f5498e30683c384d12dbd1bf845e

Comment: What does "better" mean here exactly? It's unclear exactly what you want. If you want someone to review working code, use [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: I edited the description so that it is more clear but maybe I will try Code Review since it _is_ working code

Comment: cross-posted: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239966/r-simplify-nested-for-loop-which-removes-rows-from-a-global-variable I will delete this question in 2 days if no one responds with useful information. thanks

Comment: @IanCampbell: ``??`%:%`` shows me that the `foreach` package has that: "The %:% operator is the nesting operator, used for creating nested foreach loops. Type vignette("nested") at the R prompt for more details."

Comment: How much memory do you have available? Is the actual task significantly longer than provided by your code? Your for loop took a median of  1.5 seconds on my laptop. I only have 16GB of RAM, so I could only make so many copies. Memory was so much overhead that `furrr:future_map2()` took waaaay long.

Comment: ahh I see... I thought that it might be possible to use the same raster object for all the loops. I only have 10GB of RAM (8+2onboard weird i know..) but I don't run out when I run it in the sequential for loop... I guess that's because it just needs to only slightly modify the raster so it doesn't take much RAM. hmmmmm that could put a wrench in my plans to make this faster. right now it's taking about 20 hours to run on 2 million points

Comment: if you have code for furrr:future_map2. It would be a useful answer... maybe I could spin up a VM with large RAM... I would probably need 344GB of RAM tho.... but maybe it would only take 30mins

Comment: it could process in parallel and then output `pts` only the ids which exist in all 41^2 outputs